# How to dynamically provide column name and update the record in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to store column name in varibale `@myColumn` and then use `Update` command. How can this be done ? Is it possible ?

```
    DECLARE @myColumn varchar(20)
    SET @myColumn = 'State'
    UPDATE Country SET @myColumn = 'Florida' WHERE Id = 1
```

Update:
I asked this question for using on my local test database for my special requirement only. I wanted to know if that was possible. As some have mentioned about XY problem, I want to let everyone know this is a specific requirement for my local test database and is not for professional use.

Comment: You *can't* use a variable to replace a literal, in this case a column's name. You would have to use dynamic SQL. The fact, however, that you want to do this suggests an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). *Why* do you want/need to do this?

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.  This leaves Dynamic SQL

Comment: *Side Note: The data type for an object name is `sysname`, a synonym/alias type for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`. `varchar(20)` is not an appropriate data type for a column's name.*

Comment: Still posting images of data? _DON'T DO THAT!_

Comment: If the value is also parameterized you could use a series of CASE expressions (one for each column) or for json/xml (with a slight overhead) instead of dymamic sql

Comment: Your last three questions contained images of data and got downvotes. I suggest you tak @JoelCoehoorn 's advice

Comment: I will not post images of data from now onwards. Actually it was copied from Excel file and it was posted as image.

Answer (score 4):

To dynamically use the name of a column you'll need Dynamic SQL.

Here's an example:

> ```
> DECLARE @myColumn SYSNAME
>       , @myValue VARCHAR(20)
>       , @myId INT;
>       
> DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(MAX)
>       , @UpdateSql NVARCHAR(MAX)
>       , @UpdateParams NVARCHAR(MAX);
>
> SET @myColumn = 'State';
> SET @myValue = 'Florida';
> SET @myId = 1;
>
> SET @UpdateSql = 'UPDATE Country'+CHAR(10)
>        + 'SET [COLUMN] = @Value' +CHAR(10) 
>        + 'WHERE Id = @Id';
> SET @UpdateParams = '@Value varchar(20), @Id int';
>
> SET @DynSql = REPLACE(@UpdateSql, '[COLUMN]', QUOTENAME(@myColumn));
>
> -- SELECT @DynSql As DynSql;
> EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql, @UpdateParams
>                     , @Value = @myValue
>                     , @Id = @myId;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Country WHERE ID = 1;
> ```

| ID | CountryName | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | United States of America | Florida |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca0bd0237e1ca3f4ba39a71704f62978)*

Comment: @Charlieface Oh yeah, that obscure datatype. Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible with some dynamic SQL. If you have complete control in the process, you can try this solution:

Let's create a temp table to show:

```
create table #temp ([id] int, [state] varchar(10));

Insert into #temp
SELECT 1 as ID, null as [state]

select * from #temp
```

Now that's created, let's try

```
DECLARE @myColumn varchar(20), @sql varchar(400)
SET @myColumn = '[state]'

set @sql = CONCAT('Update #temp SET ',@myColumn ,'= ''FLORIDA'' where ID = 1')

exec(@sql)
```

Check the results

```
select * from #temp
```

If you don't have complete control over the process, you need to save your code from SQL Injection.