# Is it possible to build this table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables, a Sales table and a Payment table structured like the below.

[image]

The 2 are joined using the ContractID column. What I want to see is a matrix that shows me at the top, the sum of (sold amount) per monthyear. Then on the left, I want to see the payment dates by month year, and any payments that have been made. My ideal output would look like the below.

[image]

The yellow line being the total sold by month-year, and the green lines being all the payments that have been made from the payments table. I don't really know where to start with this one, does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this? I am going to unpivot the sold table first to get my dates across the top, just pondering the next step to pull this table together?

Comment: You *could* but such a result set is by far better done in the presentation layer (or more likely, the reporting layer). Presumably the date columns need to be dynamic, which means dynamic SQL, which is a path best only walked down if you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: Impossible is impossible. for better help update your question and add script instead of image. Also try more googling and see what is PIVOT. It helps you alot

Comment: I do not understand your green lines. For example, you have `50` on the intersection of `Feb-22` & `Feb-22`. How did you come up with this number?

Comment: Because the ContractID was sold in feb 2022 and also we received a payment for said contractID in feb 2022. If it was sold in January it would have been added to the 400 figure

Comment: As alluded to by others, do the formatting in your application/reporting/presentation layer, not in the database.  In SQL you should do the calcuations and keep the results in a SQL friendly (normalised) structure.  Such as 4 columns; sale_month, payment_month, sale_amount, payment_amount *(each row of data then represents one cell in your pivot table)*.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Thank you @MatBailie, really useful takeaway for me to have a think about :)

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't understand wrong, it should be like this.

```
  WITH PaymentMatrix
  AS
  (
  SELECT
      PaymentMonth,
      SoldAmount,
      [1] AS Jan,
      [2] AS Feb,
      [3] AS Mrz,
      [4] AS Apr,
      [5] AS Mai,
      [6] AS Jun,
      [7] AS Jul,
      [8] AS Aug,
      [9] AS Sep,
      [10] AS Okt,
      [11] AS Nov,
      [12] AS Dez
  FROM
  (
  Select
  MONTH(S.SoldDate) as  SoldMonth,
  MONTH(P.PaymentDate) as PaymentMonth,
  SUM(S.SoldAmount) as SoldAmount, 
  SUM(P.PaymentAmount) as PaymentAmount
  from Sales S
  INNER JOIN Payment P ON S.ContractID = P.ContractID 
  GROUP BY 
  MONTH(S.SoldDate), 
  MONTH(P.PaymentDate) 
    ) source
  PIVOT
  (
      SUM(PaymentAmount)
      FOR SoldMonth
      IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
  ) AS pvtMonth
  )

  SELECT
   PaymentMonth, 
   SUM(SoldAmount) AS Sold,
   sum(Jan)as Jan , sum(Feb) as Feb, sum(Mrz) as Mrz, sum(Apr) as Apr, sum(Mai) as Mai, 
   sum(Jun)as Jun , sum(Jul) as Jul, sum(Aug) as Aug, sum(Sep) as Sep, sum(Okt) as Okt,
   sum(Nov) as Nov, sum(Dez) as Dez   
  FROM PaymentMatrix
  GROUP BY PaymentMonth
```

[Fidler Sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=438bd80e7af362f1d9d70fd081b0060a)

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSDQQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using conditional aggregation and a union.
Since the PIVOT syntax is more limited.

> ```
> SELECT [Sold], [Jan-22], [Feb-22], [Mar-22]
> FROM
> (
> SELECT 0 as Seq, 'Paid' AS [Sold]
> , SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT([Sold Date],'MMM-yy') = 'Jan-22' 
>       THEN [Sold Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan-22]
> , SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT([Sold Date],'MMM-yy') = 'Feb-22' 
>       THEN [Sold Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb-22]
> , SUM(CASE WHEN FORMAT([Sold Date],'MMM-yy') = 'Mar-22' 
>       THEN [Sold Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar-22]
> FROM Sales
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT m.Seq, m.PaymentMonth 
> , SUM(CASE WHEN SoldMonth = 'Jan-22' THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan-22]
> , SUM(CASE WHEN SoldMonth = 'Feb-22' THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb-22]
> , SUM(CASE WHEN SoldMonth = 'Mar-22' THEN PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar-22]
> FROM (VALUES
> (1,'Jan-22'),
> (2,'Feb-22'),
> (3,'Mar-22')
> ) m(Seq, PaymentMonth)
> LEFT JOIN (
>   SELECT ContractID
>   , FORMAT(EOMONTH([Payment Date]), 'MMM-yy') AS PaymentMonth
>   , SUM([Payment Amount]) AS PaymentAmount
>   FROM Payment
>   GROUP BY ContractID, EOMONTH([Payment Date])
> ) p ON p.PaymentMonth = m.PaymentMonth
> LEFT JOIN (
>   SELECT ContractID
>   , FORMAT(MAX([Sold Date]), 'MMM-yy') AS SoldMonth
>   , SUM([Sold Amount]) AS SoldAmount
>   FROM Sales
>   GROUP BY ContractID
> ) s ON s.ContractID = p.ContractID
> GROUP BY m.Seq, m.PaymentMonth
> ) q
> ORDER BY Seq;
> ```

> | Sold | Jan-22 | Feb-22 | Mar-22 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Paid | 2500 | 100 | 0 |
> | Jan-22 | 300 | 0 | 0 |
> | Feb-22 | 400 | 50 | 0 |
> | Mar-22 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e9f74b60f69f975a7806f46d3870ef7a)*

Comment: Ooh this is really useful & similar to the approach I was first thinking of. The only thing is it's not fully dynamic? i.e each month year needs to be coded in manually.. but then gain I guess I'd only have to update it once a month :)

Comment: Dynamic Sql is required the moment you want to have [column names that depend on the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54678913/4003419) and you don't want to hardcode them.

Comment: You could also opt for more generic names. Like only the months without year. `[Sold], [SoldYear], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar],... `